# Convert xml to CLR type using Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have following xml structure

```
<quiz xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="quiz.xsd">
    <mchoice>
        <question>What is the capital city of Australia?</question>
        <answer>Sydney</answer>
        <answer correct="yes">Canberra</answer>
        <answer>Melbourne</answer>
        <answer>Gold Coast</answer>
    </mchoice>
</quiz>
```

and I want to convert it into CLR type using following code

```
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<Answer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class Answer
{
    public string Answer1 { get; set; }
    public string Answer2 { get; set; }
    public string Answer3 { get; set; }
    public string Answer4 { get; set; }

}




public List<Question> GetAll()
        {
            var doc = XDocument.Load(Filepath);
            var results = (from x in doc.Descendants("mchoice")
                           select new Question()
                                      {
                                          ID = Convert.ToInt16(x.Element("ID")),
                                          QuestionText = x.Element("question").Value.ToString(),
                                          Answers = new List<Answer>()
                                          {
                                             //How I would fill Answer collection

                                          }


                                      }).ToList();
            return results;
        }
```

Now I have two problem with current design.

1. How I would fill the Answer collection
2. How I would handle correct answer attribute in current design.

Comment: your model is "wrong" (or let's say not coherent) : either you have a `List<Answer>` in Question (then you don't need Answer1, Answer2, Answer3 in Answer, but only a `public string AnswerText`) or you have a `public Answer {get;set;}` in Question, not a List...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with first idea

```
    public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public Answer Answer { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string Answer1 { get; set; }
        public string Answer2 { get; set; }
        public string Answer3 { get; set; }
        public string Answer4 { get; set; }

    }
var results = (from x in doc.Descendants("mchoice")
               let answers = x.Elements("answer")
               select new Question()
                 {
                      ID = Convert.ToInt16(x.Element("ID")),
                      QuestionText = x.Element("question").Value,
                      Answer = new Answer
                        {
                            Answer1 = answers.First().Value,
                            Answer2 = answers.Skip(1).First().Value,
                            Answer3 = answers.Skip(2).First().Value,
                            Answer4 = answers.Last().Value
                         }


                  }).ToList();
```

with an easier Model

```
public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<string> AnswerTextList { get; set; }
    }

var results = (from x in doc.Descendants("mchoice")

                           select new Question()
                           {
                               ID = Convert.ToInt16(x.Element("ID")),
                               QuestionText = x.Element("question").Value,
                               AnswerTextList = (x.Elements("answer").Select(m => m.Value.ToString()).ToList())
                           }).ToList();
```

with a GOOD model

```
public class Question
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string QuestionText { get; set; }
        public List<Answer> AnswerList { get; set; }
    }

    public class Answer
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    }

var results = (from x in doc.Descendants("mchoice")
        select new Question()
        {
            ID = Convert.ToInt16(x.Element("ID")),
            QuestionText = x.Element("question").Value,
            AnswerList = (x.Elements("answer").Select(m => new Answer
            {
                Text = m.Value,
                IsCorrect = m.Attribute("correct") != null && m.Attribute("correct").Value == "yes"
            }).ToList())
        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there is a mismatch in your model.  You have four separate "Answer" properties in the `Answer` class.  However, your `Question` class contains a list of `Answer` objects.  And the XML contains four answers corresponding to a single question.  It seems like a more accurate model of a question would look something like either:

```
public class Question
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answers { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswerIndex { get; set; } 
}
```

in which case the `Answer` class could be ignored entirely,

or, you could keep the `Question` class as is and change the `Answer` class to look more like

```
public class  Answer
{
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

If you use either of these approaches, it will be much easier to see how you can do the XML mapping.  However, as you have presented the problem, **there is no correct answer, because the design is fundamentally flawed**.

With the first example, you could do the XML-Object mapping as @L.B. suggests.  However, you would need to set the `CorrectAnswerIndex` property equal to the index of the correct answer string in the list.